# Make "Upload Date" Appear On Frontend - WP Simple Download Manager

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

**The Rundown:**

I'm using [a Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-download-monitor/) to manage my downloadables, and I'm trying to figure out how to make the "Upload Date" appear on the front-end. I added code that I thought would do the job, but nothing happened.

I found 3 areas that I thought I was suppose to focus on.

**PHP:**

```
function handle_sdm_download_via_direct_post() {
if (isset($_REQUEST['smd_process_download']) && $_REQUEST['smd_process_download'] == '1') {
    global $wpdb;
    $download_id = strip_tags($_REQUEST['download_id']);
    $download_title = get_the_title($download_id);
    $download_date = get_the_date($format, $post_id);
    $download_link = get_post_meta($download_id, 'sdm_upload', true);
```

I added `$download_date = get_the_date($format, $post_id);`

---

```
// Create array of variables to pass to js
    $final_array[] = array('id' => $post->ID, 'permalink' => get_permalink($post->ID), 'title' => $post->post_title, 'date' => $post->post_date);
```

I added `, 'date' => $post->post_date)`

---

**JS:**

```
// Populate each matched post title and permalink
    $this.children('.sdm_placeholder').append('<a href="'+value['permalink']+'"><span class="sdm_post_title" style="cursor:pointer;">'+value['title']+'</span></a><span class="sdm_post_date">'+value['date']+'</span>');
```

I added the `<span class="sdm_post_date">'+value['date']+'</span>` part, but I'm not sure if that's correct, and I'm not sure I defined it correctly in the PHP :/

**Link To The Files If Necessary:**

**PHP:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C2-SqaSCluYXZlcmUtNFF0NzA/view?usp=sharing

**JS:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C2-SqaSCluenVSRFpzV3V3Z0E/view?usp=sharing